# Help with visualizing the surface to be able to calculate the line integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

We are given the vector field
$F(x,y,z)=[2z+y, 2x+z, 2ycos(z)]$

A surface S is composed of two parts. One part $S_1$ given by $z=x^2+y^2$, for $0\leq z\leq4$ and $0 \leq y$. The second part $S_2$ is given by $x^2 \leq z \leq 4$ for $y=0$. Let C be the edge of S, oriented counterclockwise seen from above.

a) Sketch the surface S and show the orientation of C on the sketch.

b) Based on the parameterization of C calculate $\oint_C F\bullet \,dr$

c)Let S have an orientation that is consistent with the orientation of C, and let N be the external normal vector to . Find
$\iint_S curl(F) \bullet N dS$

So I have problems visualiazing how the surface S actually look like. For $S_1$ I know that this must be a parabola with height 4. Since $y\geq0$ this must be half of a parabola (that part lying over the first and second quadrant. For the surface $S_2$ however, I have now idea how it looks like. The inequality makes me a bit confused to be honest. I would really appreciate some help understanding how S looks like. I guess that if I know the surface and the edge of it, both b) and c) should give the same answer given Stokes theorem?

Comment: $S_1$ describes a paraboloid, but only the half associated with $y\ge 0.$  $S_2,$ describes the parabola in the xz-plane (and its interior).  i.e. imagine a paraboloid solid that was cut in half.  one surface is the exterior of what remains of the original paraboloid, the other is the surface revealed by slicing.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I understand it now!